# How to find activities attached to a View?

Tags: unix, clearcase, cleartool, clearquest

I would like to find the activity which I previously set to a view.

Is there a command that I can use to find out all the activities set to the view?

Say view name is myView and activity is PRTLB12345. I had set the activity to the view like

"**cleartool startview myView**" 
You can now run 'clearquest' to start Rational ClearQuest.

"**cleartool setactivity PRTLB1234**5"
Set activity "PRTLB12345" in view "myView".

Here PRTLB12345 is a dummy activity name and I need to find out the real activity that I set to myview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cleartool lsact -cview would list all activities for the current view.

cleartool lsact -l -cact will list and detail the currency set activity, in the current view.

Comment: I prefer this **cleartool lsact -l -cact** because it list only my activities created using my ID rather than the cleartool **lsact -cview** as it list downs all the activities created for that view by any of my team member.